# Certain elements wont prepend to the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to figure this out for hours to no avail. What is happening is that only part of the "completeLi" variable is being prepended into the document. The parts that aren't are the span tags with the classes of "done" and "delete". As you can see I even attempt to assign icons to them to no avail also.

Note: This is jQuery and jQuery UI.

Thanks for any assistance you can give.

```
$("#addToDo").on("click", function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault(); 
                $("#new-todo").dialog({ 
                    modal: true,    
                    height: 300,    
                    width: 300,
                    close : function(){ 
                        $("#new-todo input").val("");
                    },
                    buttons : { 
                        "Add Task" : function(){    
                            var tasks = $("#task").val();   
                            var dueTime = $("#due-date").val(); 
                            var completeLi = '<li><span class="done">X</span><span class = "task">' + tasks + '</span><span class ="due-date">' + dueTime + '</span><span class="delete">X</span></li>';

                            $("#to-do-list").prepend(completeLi); 
                            $("#to-do-list").hide().slideDown(300).find("li:first") 
                                    .animate({  
                                        'background-color': 'rgb(232, 230, 198)'
                                    }, 300)
                                    .animate({  
                                        'background-color' : '#E8E6C6'
                                    }, 200).animate();
                            $(this).dialog('close'); 
                        },
                        'Cancel' : function(){  
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            $("#addToDo").button({  
                icons : {
                    primary : "ui-icon-circle-plus"
                }
            });
            $(".done").button({ 
                icons : {
                    primary : "ui-icon-check"
                },
                cursor: 'pointer'
            });
            $(".delete").button({  
                icons : {
                    primary : "ui-icon-closethick"
                },
                cursor: 'pointer'
            });
```

Comment: Provide necessary html too if possible!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1trx79no/1/ - looks fine

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1trx79no/2/ - You need to initialize the button plugin for the new elements after they are created

Comment: @GuruprasadRao here is where it will be prepended to.  Specifically in the "to-do-list" class ul. Sorry about the crap formatting. I'm new here and not sure how to get it to work



<div id="to-do">
                <h2>To Do Item List</h2>
                <!--<span class="delete"></span><span class="done"></span>-->
                <ul id="to-do-list" class="sortable"></ul>
            </div>
            <div id="completed">
                <h2>Complete</h2>
                <ul id="complete-list" class="sortable"></ul>
            </div>

Comment: But I think @ArunPJohny here just solved it. Thanks!

Comment: hmmmm just popped that into my code and it comes up with the error of "Uncaught TypeError: completeLi.find is not a function"